# How to show selected date inside the button ---- Date picker -- Flutter

Tags: flutter, datepicker

**I have built a date picker where users can select the date and I want to update the selected date inside the elevated button, but when the date is updated it also starts showing the time inside the elevated button
Also, I want to keep the same format of date, I have specified above in the code
I am providing my code and snapshots**

```
[class CashInCashOut extends StatefulWidget {
  const CashInCashOut({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CashInCashOutState createState() => _CashInCashOutState();
}

class _CashInCashOutState extends State<CashInCashOut> {
  DateTime date = DateTime.now();
  late var formattedDate = DateFormat('d-MMM-yy').format(date);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Cash Out"),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: \[
              const TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Amount"),
              ),
              const TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Detail (optional)"),
              ),
              Row(
                children: \[
                  ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text(formattedDate),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      DateTime? _newDate = await showDatePicker(
                        context: context,
                        initialDate: date,
                        firstDate: DateTime(2022),
                        lastDate: DateTime(2030),
                      );
                      setState(() {
                        if (_newDate == null) {
                          return;
                        } else {
                          formattedDate = _newDate.toString();
                        }
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  const Spacer(),
                  ReusableButton(text: "Add bills"),
                \],
              ),
            \],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

[state of my application before selecting date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG29r.jpg)

[state of my application after selecting the date from date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfDrT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you forgot to format the date when the date was chosen.
In the onPressed function where you are setting the state, you have to write it as:

```
if (_newDate == null) {
     return;
   } else {
     formattedDate = DateFormat('d-MMM-yy').format(_newDate);
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: problem solved.

Comment: oh good, kindly accept the answer and close this.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);


    final String title;

    @override
    State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
  }

  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    DateTime date = DateTime.now();
    late var formattedDate;
    @override
    void initState() {
      formattedDate = DateFormat('d-MMM-yy').format(date);
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              child: Text(formattedDate),
              onPressed: () async {
                await showDatePicker(
                  context: context,
                  initialDate: date,
                  firstDate: DateTime(2022),
                  lastDate: DateTime(2030),
                ).then((selectedDate) {
                  if (selectedDate != null) {
                    setState(() {
                       date = selectedDate;
                       formattedDate = DateFormat('d-MMM-yy').format(selectedDate);
                    });
                  }
                }
                );

              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }


  }
```

this is how it looks when you start the app:

[image]

if you press the button and you chose for example this date 25-mar-2025 :

[image]

then click ok, the date will appear in the button :

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. You people are awesome

Comment: I loved to, but they are saying you need at least reputation of 15 to cast a vote

Answer (score 0):

You should format the date when the button is pressed. Just replace this code portion with yours:

```
if (_newDate == null) {
    return
} else {
    formattedDate = DateFormat.yMd().format(_newDate);
}
```

***Note:*** You can change date format according to what you want. Just change `yMd` to any other format you want. Hover over `DateFormat`, and your IDE will help you.